# Draw UITablveViewCell in background thread, is it possible?

Tags: ios, tableview

For better performance on scrolling the UItableView. I was adviced to draw the cells in a background thread.

But some one said that, update UI in background thread is not recommended, this can crash the app.

Is it possible to draw cells in background thread?

Comment: If you are having performance problems with scrolling then you should show us the code you are using in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Otherwise we do not know what is really happening. As for drawing in background, it is a bad idea. But, if you are loading resources from the network then you should load in the background then update the cell on the main thread.

Comment: The cell is complicated,and the codes is too long.

Comment: can I create and layout the subviews in background thread, after the layout finish, just switch back to the main thread, set subview's frame?

Comment: "The cell is complicated,and the codes is too long." - well, maybe that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You very well can draw on a background thread - and then capture that drawing as an image and send that back to the main thread; there an image view displays the image you draw in the background.

If you have access to the Apple developer site, watch the WWDC 2012 Video "Building Concurrent  User Interfaces on iOS". You don't want to actually lay out UIView instances and so forth but just use the various Core Graphics drawing functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that , every view would draw itself at the time when it comes to foreground, it would do nothing in background.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing UI in background not only **can** crash but in most cases **will** crash the app.

Make sure you're using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` message for getting cells.

Revise your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate to find what consumes most resources. It could be, e.q. hard UIImage processing or something similar. You should consider move all the processing, generating data and such things out of your cell creating. Only set appropriate data in cell and return it. I'm pretty sure it'll reduce your performance issues greatly.